# How to send email using a variable as recipient Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

The send email action lets you use a workflow variable. When I have the recipient set to a variable with my email address and try to run the workflow I get the message:

> BadRequest to ../_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail

Comment: And when you manually type the email address into the recipient field it works fine?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work using return field as Login Name and Login Name semi colon delimited. When returned as String, Email, and Display Name I received the error above even if the value was in the format expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, In email recipient, if you are not using a "person or group column", then you have to use login name for the recipient or valid SharePoint user email address . Because internally SharePoint 2013 will try to resolve the principal of the mentioned user. As a part of security validation this has been introduced in SharePoint 2013.

```
SPUtility.SendEmail - This method supports sending email messages only to valid SharePoint user email addresses.
```